# $\exists!x\exists!yP(x,y)$ is not the same as $\exists!y\exists!xP(x,y)$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Suppose $P(x,y)$ is a property pertaining to any object $x$ and $y$.
Let $\exists!$ be the unique existential quantifier.

Then I just found that $\exists!x\exists!yP(x,y)$ is not necessarily equivalent to $\exists!y\exists!xP(x,y)$ , generally.

For instance, suppose that $P(1,0),P(2,1),P(2,2)$ are true statements, otherwise $P(x,y)$ is false. Then clearly $\exists!x\exists!yP(x,y)$ is true but $\exists!y\exists!xP(x,y)$ is false.

Then how can I express sentences such as "there exists a unique **pair** of sets $x$ and $y$ such that $P(x,y)$" , meaning that there exists an object $x$ and an object $y$ such that $P(x,y)$ and that $x=x'\land y=y'$ whenever $P(x,y)\land P(x',y')$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "express"? Do you mean using $\exists, \wedge$ etc, or do you mean to ask whether there is a single symbol that expresses this?

Comment: @Trebor I wish to find a most natural way to "express" that sentence. I have no background in mathematical logic. I think I'm seeking a neat expression using $\exists$, $\forall$, etc. And it would be great if there were a single symbol. Because I think the expression $\exists x\exists y P(x,y)\land\forall x\forall y\forall x'\forall y'(P(x,y)\land P(x',y')\rightarrow (x=x'\land y=y'))$ is way too cumbersome.

Comment: You can always just invent new symbols, so $\exists! xy, P(x, y)$ seems reasonable.

Comment: @AnneBauval Could you explain why they're equivalent? I think I found a counterexample. Suppose $P(1,0), P(2,1), P(2,2)$ are true statements, otherwise $P(x,y)$ is false. Then $\exists!x\exists!y P(x,y)$. Howevwer, $\exists!y\exists!x P(x,y)$ is false.

Comment: Oops my bad! I deleted my very wrong comment and only copied-pasted below its initial suggestion. I think your counterexample should take place inside your post.

Comment: @Trebor Rather $∃!(x,y)P(x,y)$. Or maybe $∃!zP(z)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\exists!x\exists yP(x,y)\land\exists!y\exists xP(x,y)$

Comment: I didn't think this answer would be so controversial: two upvotes, one downvote, an acceptance, and two votes to delete!

Comment: I think there are downvotes and votes to delete because your answer appears to be wrong at first glance to an amateur, i.e., me!  But $\exists!x\exists yP(x,y)\land\exists!y\exists xP(x,y)$ is indeed equivalent to the proposition that I had difficulty writing out, as I have verified. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

While bof's:

$\exists ! x \exists y P(x,y) \land \exists ! y \exists x (P(x,y)$

is certainly very efficient, I would suggest:

$\exists x \exists y \forall x' \forall y' (P(x',y') \leftrightarrow (x' = x \land y' = y))$

Note how this expression contains only one $P(x,y)$ formula. So it is definitely more efficient than your:

$\exists x \exists y P(x,y) \land \forall x \forall y \forall x' \forall y' (P(x,y) \rightarrow (x = x' \land y = y'))$

And, if $P(x,y)$ is a complicated formula, my suggested expression could well be more efficient than bof's.

In fact, this method generalizes well to triples, quadruples, etc. For example, to say there is exactly one triple, you get:

$\exists x \exists y \exists z \forall x' \forall y' \forall z' (P(x',y',z') \leftrightarrow (x' = x \land y' = y \land z' = z))$

So, still just one $P(x,y,z)$ formula!

Note how with your method you also still have two formulas:

$\exists x \exists y \exists z P(x,y,z) \land \forall x \forall y \forall z \forall x' \forall y' \forall z' (P(x,y,z) \rightarrow (x = x' \land y = y' \land z = z'))$

But with bof's strategy you now need three:

$\exists ! x \exists y \exists z P(x,y,z) \land \exists ! y \exists x \exists z (P(x,y,z) \land \exists ! z \exists x \exists y (P(x,y,z) $

And finally, if you were to actually use these expressions in, say, some formal proof, having 'plain' existentials is often more practical than having 'unique' existentials.

Answer (score 1):

It's nearly always a good idea (in my humble opinion) to specify the domain that you are working with—though it sometimes causes extra notational confusion, it can also work wonders for clarity!

For example, assuming that the domain/universe for $x$ is $X$ and the domain/universe for $y$ is $Y$, one way is to write $(\exists ! (x,y) \in X \times Y)P(x,y)$. The set $X \times Y$ is exactly the set of ordered pairs where the first element comes from $X$ and the second from $Y$, and this expression then reads "there is a unique ordered pair of elements $x$ and $y$ from the sets $X$ and $Y$ respectively such that $P(x,y)$ is true".

Comment: I don't think that specifying the domain is relevant to the OP's qestion. You can simply write $\exists ! (x,y) \;P(x,y)$, and this expression then reads "there is a unique ordered pair of elements $x$ and $y$ such that $P(x,y)$ is true".